# Vuetify and nuxt.js - Rules should return a string or boolean, received 'undefined' instead

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have made a App in my work. In text-area, error occured like my title. I googled same issues and I read it but I crearly understand about that kind of issues.

My goal is I want to use literal as object.
but I think rules can't use literal object.
I'm super beginner and I'm not good at English.
If you understand please ask me!

```
    <template>
    <v-card width="600" persistent>
        <v-card-tex>
            <v-row>
            <v-col cols="8">
                <v-textarea 
                    filed 
                    dense
                    v-model="testtext"
                    :rules="v=>!!v||'this is required!'"></v-textarea>
            </v-col>
        </v-row>
        </v-card-tex>
    </v-card>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import {Vue} from 'nuxt-property-decorator'

export default class extends Vue{
   testtext:string= `test`
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you should use the rules like this in v-textarea :

```
:rules="[v => !!v||'this is required!']"
```